# "within c hops" or "within c-hops"

Tags: hyphens

I am writing a paper. In the paper, I originally wrote

> all vertices that are within **c hops** of a vertex v

but my teacher later changed it to

> all vertices that are within **c-hops** of a vertex v

Here, the letter "c" represents a fixed constant. I wonder what is the difference between them. I frequently heard people say something like "... is within 2 miles of ...". So I think mine is the correct one.

Comment: Isn't this really a *mathematics* question?

Comment: Definitely no hyphen.  Ideally, you'd use some typography to identify constants and variables as distinct from text, like this: "all vertices that are within *c* hops of a vertex *v*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the version without the hyphen.

The variable name should be formatted consistently. Normally this would mean using an italic typeface for the variable.

For example, from [Cambridge, statslab](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~mike/probability/example3-solutions.pdf)

> **Problem 6**. A flea hops randomly on the vertices of a triangle with vertices labelled 1,2,
>   and 3, hopping to each of the other vertices with equal probability. If the flea starts at vertex
>   1, find the probability that after *n* hops the flea is back to vertex 1.

(In a Latex source file you would write "after $n$~hops", the dollar signs put TeX into math mode, and the ~ prevents a line break.)

(see also [maths stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450289/flea-on-a-triangle))

Answer (score -2):

You know, I think this is more of a *mathematics* question than an *English* question.

Adding a hyphen between two words in English is normally to link them. You don't want to link these because they aren't connected words - "c" represent a number, and you wouldn't write "3-hops".

The problem is, "c hops" looks like "chops"!

Why not use some other means to make the "c" stand out, such as *italics*?

In fact, I'm fairly certain that in maths papers they normally italicise letters in algebra.

> All vertices that are within *c* hops of a vertex *v*.

Comment: The "c" is italic in the paper. So the problem mentioned does not exist, I think.

Comment: @Gedt To be honest then, we are second-guessing your *teacher's* reasons for changing it. My guess is that he thought it looked like 'chops'.